# Пространство у изображения после width

Tags: html, css

Возможно очень легкий вопрос, но я новичек в этом и не нашел решения. Мне нужно разместить иконку "крестика" сверху справа страницы, использую флекс. После применения width: 12% у изображения появляется невидимый отступ, как его убрать?

[Ссылка с кодом](https://codepen.io/kolyageshko/pen/YzQbyqe)

```
            <div class="product-photo-view-header">
            <div class="close-button">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/S83HZ33.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
.product-photo-view {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.product-photo-view-header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #1d1d;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.close-button {
  float: right;
}

.close-button img {
  width: 12%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Засомневался, о каком отступе вопрос. У контейнера .close-button не задана ширина. Если её установить соразмерной крестику, то крестик окажется ближе к правому углу. А вот float:right можно убрать, оно не работает внутри flex-контейнера.

Comment: Что касается появления микроотступа **под** img, то вот [история вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему вам надо задать ширину 12% для .close-button и для .close-button img - width: 100%, крестик станет справа

Comment: спасибо, помогло